# Closing connections in convenience class

Tags: java, jdbc

My current design pattern includes a large number of database access methods in a single convenience class. When it's instantiated it grabs the connections it needs and waits for methods.

It was my thinking that opening a single connection when I'm about to run 10 methods with that connection would be better than opening and closing that connection for each of the 10 individual methods.

However, I've realised that I don't close any of these connections. I've come to the conclusion that I'll have to go back and refactor all calls to the method to include a `closeConnections` method which will release all active connections.

My question is this:
should I open and close connections in each and every method, following good design practice (will this incur significant overhead), or should I refactor calls to the convenience class with a call to a `closeConnections` method

Psuedocode

```
class convenience{
    public contructor(){
        a = new Connection();
    }

    public void methodA(){
        /* do stuff */
    }
    public void methodB(){
        /* do stuff */
    }
    public void methodC(){
        /* do stuff */
        //should I do this?
        a = new Connection();
        /* do stuff */
        a.close();
    }
    public void close(){
        //or this
        a.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you pass a connection object when making the convenience method calls?

Comment: That was my original design implementation. I had one single connection which was shared amongst all classes and really abused. I replaced that with opening/closing connections on an as needed base to be more resistant to network interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should not keep the connection in this convenience class, but pass it in on each method invocation. That way you will be able to control the lifetime of the connection, and - for example - use transactions in a useful way.

Also keeping this connection inside this convenience class increases the risk of sharing a connection with multiple threads, which in general is not advisable.

Incurring the cost of opening and closing connections can be alleviated/removed by using a connection pool like c3p0, DBCP, BoneCP (and others).

Comment: I implemented it such that the convenience class is fairly minimal, and a new instance is created on an as needed basis to avoid sharing connections (will that problem persist? I'm not aware here). I've been intending to look in to a connection pool. That's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that whenever you open a connection, you should register it to a service. You can then later on check with the service if the particular connection is open or already closed to take car of the leaks in the application.

Answer (score 0):

> following good design practice

If you want that then don't re-invent the wheel. Use a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

Comment: I've not worked with connection pools before. Is this something I'll have to instantiate a connection to each time the convenience class is instantiated, or is it something I'll keep a single instance of and pass to each and every instantiation of the convenience class?

Comment: In a nutshell, you get a connection from a pool and return it back to the pool (by explicitely closing the connection).All the other details are handled by the pool.You just use the connection.Depending on how you access the pool you could for example have a `DataSource` and reuse that across all objects to get a connection from `DataSource`.